# count the ways to reach nth step using step 1,2 and 3 but take step 3 only k times

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am able solve this problem using recursion. Here is the code

```
int countstep(int n,int k){
    if(n<0)
        return 0;
    if(n==0)
        return 1;
    int total_step=countstep(n-1,k)+countstep(n-2,k);
    if(k>0)
        total_step+=countstep(n-3,k-1);
    return total_step;
}
```

Problem is I'm not able to figure out how to implement this in tabulation way.

Comment: What do you mean by *tabulation*? Memoization?

Answer (score 0):

The code is essentially the same as the recursive formula, except you compute the function for every possible value of n and k (up to limits) and store results in an appropriately sized array (table). You have to be careful not to access the table out of bounds.

Here's a solution in Python, optimized for readability rather that maximum efficiency.

```
def countstep(N, K):
    table = [[None] * (K+1) for _ in range(N+1)]
    for k in range(K+1):
        table[0][k] = 1
    for n in range(1, N+1):
        for k in range(K+1):
            t = 0
            if n >= 1:
                t += table[n-1][k]
            if n >= 2:
                t += table[n-2][k]
            if n >= 3 and k > 0:
                t += table[n-3][k-1]
            table[n][k] = t
    return table[N][K]
```

You can, with some care, make the table 4 by K+1 rather than N+1 by K+1, since at every point, you're only interested in the table entries for the last 4 values of N. Here's a version that does this (note that it uses the python feature that accessing an array with a negative index returns an element from the end of the list (eg: `table[-2]` is the next-to-last row of `table`)).

```
def countstep(N, K):
    table = [[None] * (K+1) for _ in range(4)]
    for k in range(K+1):
        table[0][k] = 1
    for n in range(1, N+1):
        for k in range(K+1):
            ti = n % 4
            t = 0
            if n >= 1:
                t += table[ti-1][k]
            if n >= 2:
                t += table[ti-2][k]
            if n >= 3 and k > 0:
                t += table[ti-3][k-1]
            table[ti][k] = t
    return table[N%4][K]
```

Comment: Hello, I was thinking that this problem is a modified version of the tribonacci numbers where after k=0 it reduces to the fibonacci numbers for the rest, where n1 = 1, n2=2, n3=4 (if k > 0) and for each ni we calculate ni-1+ni-2+ni-3 if k > 0 else just ni-1+ni-2. This would reduce the problem to constant space and the n time complexity. I'm not sure about my thinking. Can you advise if this is correct or I'm missing something? Thanks.

Comment: @user1984 no, this isn't right. If you try to code it up, you'll either find your logic problems, or you can just compare the results to a correct implementation (eg the original recursive definition). The root of the problem is that you have to account exactly for how many 3-steps you've made.

Comment: @user1984 There's two edge cases where your idea works. For k=0 you get fibonacci numbers, and k>=n you get tribonacci numbers.

Comment: I thought at first we could keep track of the number of `k`s we have used and drop the 3rd step whenever `k=0`, but then I doubted this reasoning of mine because when `k < n` we could expend our `k`s at different steps of the path (we are not required to use them all in the first `k+2` steps). This makes my idea wrong and the need for the `n * k` table arises. Is this correct?